# How to iterate through different sci-kit learn classifiers

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, scikit-learn, global

I'm running a bunch of models with scikit-learn to solve a classification problem.

How do I iterate through different scikit-learn models?

```
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.dummy import DummyClassifier

classifiers_name = ['AdaBoostClassifier',
                    'BernoulliNB',
                    'DummyClassifier']

def fitting_classifier(clf, X_train, y_train):
    return clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

for clf_n in classifiers_name:
    locals()['results_' + clf_n] = fitting_classifier(locals()[clf_n + str(())], X_train, y_train)
```

I seem to be getting an error in this part of the code: `fitting_classifier(locals()[clf_n + str(())], X_train, y_train)`. The error shown is:

```
<ipython-input-31-cccf30ff4392> in summary_scores(file_path, image_format, scores)
    140         for clf_sn in classifiers_name:
--> 141             locals()['results_' + clf_n] = fitting_classifier(locals()[clf_n + str(())], X_train, y_train)
    142 
    143         # results_AdaBoostClassifier = fitting_classifier(AdaBoostClassifier(), X_train, y_train)

KeyError: 'AdaBoostClassifier()'
```

Any help with this would really be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You might be looking for https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/calibration/plot_compare_calibration.html

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/auto_examples/plot_classifier_comparison.html

Comment: Thanks. I need to iterate because I want to produce an output for a report. Would be great if you know of a way to iterate a class of a classifier

Comment: The links I posted show how to iterate the classifiers, for some there is also a loop over different datasets.

Comment: Ok many thanks for this. Will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not mentioned the purpose of this. **Why exactly you want to iterate through different scikit-learn models?**

If you are trying to find out which model of the above fits better and outperforms, you can use something like this

```
# -------- Cross validate model with Kfold stratified cross val ---------------

    kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)

# Modeling step Test differents algorithms
    classifiers = ['AdaBoostClassifier',
                    'BernoulliNB',
                    'DummyClassifier']
    results = []
    for model in classifiers :
        results.append(cross_val_score(model, X_train, y = y_train, scoring = "accuracy", cv = kfold, n_jobs=4))

    cv_means = []
    cv_std = []
    for cv_result in results:
        cv_means.append(cv_result.mean())
        cv_std.append(cv_result.std())

    cv_res = pd.DataFrame({"CrossValMeans":cv_means,"CrossValerrors": cv_std,"Algorithm":["AdaBoostClassifier","BernoulliNB","DummyClassifier"]})`
```

***If you are trying to Ensemble these***

Train them separately, and use HyperParams to find the best estimator for a model and then use ***VotingClassifier*** as:

```
    DTC = DecisionTreeClassifier()
    ADB = AdaBoostClassifier(DTC)

    ada_param_grid = { # Params here }

    gsABC = GridSearchCV(ADB,param_grid = ada_param_grid , cv=kfold, scoring="accuracy", n_jobs= 4, verbose = 1)

    AdaBoost_best =gsABC.best_estimator_

 # Likewise you can do for others and then perform Voting

    votingC = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('ada', AdaBoost_best), ('nb', BernoulliNB_best),
    ('dc', DummyClassifier_best)], voting='soft', n_jobs=4)

    votingC = votingC.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to iterate because it’s to produce an output for a report. Would be great if you know of a way to iterate a class of a classifier.